# Is there a way to get a pixels' color-value and store the value in a .txt file?

Tags: python

I want a certain image to be 'scanned' by my script and give the pixel's color values as an output inside of a .txt-file, similar to this: '1,1;255,255,255' (x,y;r,g,b).

I know the rough basics of python, I also know how to create a txt but nothing about image processing.

Any help is apreciated!

Comment: It will strongly depends on the encoding of your images. You can use a lib like Pillow to decode your images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html) library

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(...)
width, height = img.size

for x in range(width):
  for y in range(height):
    print(x+","+y+":"+img.getpixel((x, y)))
```

Then write to a new file

```py
with open('myfile.txt', 'a') as myFile:
    myFile.write('data')
```

Merge both codes

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(...)
width, height = img.size

with open('myfile.txt', 'a') as myFile:
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      myFile.write(x+","+y+":"+img.getpixel((x, y))+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using openCV, which I believe is much easier.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(img_name)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

h,w,c = img.shape

with open('myfile.txt', 'a') as file:
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
             str_to_write = "%d,%d:%d,%d,%d\n" % (x,y,img[y,x,0],img[y,x,1],img[y,x,2])
             file.write(str_to_write)
```

Surely, to each his own, but OpenCV allows you to access pixel values like indices, which makes more sense to me, though an extra step of converting to rgb is required, if you want to avoid that, you may just do

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(img_name)

h,w,c = img.shape

with open('myfile.txt', 'a') as file:
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            str_to_write = "%d,%d:%d,%d,%d\n" % (x,y,img[y,x,2],img[y,x,1],img[y,x,0])
            file.write(str_to_write)
```

Comment: Use resources to close your files automatically ```with open('myfile.txt', 'a') as myFile ...```

Comment: that wasn't entirely necessary if you just do file.close() later on, but regardless I have edited the code to make said changes

Comment: what about an exception raised during your code? Your .close() will never reach !

Comment: This wouldn't be necessary if you use try/catch/finally way to close the file. But this is much more simple using with clause.